# How can I find the min date by group when data repeats

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

So, my problem is as follows.

I have a data set with timestamp (date&time). I have another field which shows the status of a file, this status should flow from one stage to the next, but occasionally it will loop back to a prior stage. When this happens I need to show the timestamp when this change occurred.

As an example, I need to know the MIN date when an item in 'Instructed', this is fine and I have this. What I need to then know is if a file moved to 'Non Instructed' and back to 'Instructed' again, what is the MIN timestamp here - i.e. 07/01/2020 in the example, so effectively ignoring anything prior to the last time a file was at the 'Non Instructed' stage. This loop could happen multiple times, I always need to show the most recent MIN date for a file in the 'Instructed' state. I'm using MS SQL Server.

[image: Time Stamp Stage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as a gaps and island problem.

I have not tested this, due to an image being provided for sample data, but I don't doubt this will work:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT AuditTimeStamp,
           Stamp,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AuditTimeStamp) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Stage ORDER BY AuditTimeStamp) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT MIN(AuditTimeStamp) AS MinAuditTimeStamp,
       Stamp
FROM Grps
GROUP BY Stamp,
         Grp
ORDER BY MinAuditTimeStamp ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, lag(stage) over(order by audit_timestamp) lag_stage
    from mytable t
) t
where stage = 'Instructed' and (lag_stage is null or lag_stage <> 'Instructed')
```